# How to split dataframe by column value condition, pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to split a dataframe in to different lists based on column value condition.

Here is a dataframe example.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'flag_1':[1,2,3,1,2,500,498,495,1,1,1,1,1,500,440,430,2,3,4,4],'dd':[1,1,1,7,7,7,8,8,8,1,1,1,7,7,7,8,8,8,5,7]})

df_out
df_out=pd.DataFrame({'flag_1':[500,498,495,500,440,430],'dd':[7,8,8,7,7,8]})
```

Comment: what is column value condition that splits your dataframe? Please state clearly.

Comment: @ SomeDude  if value is 500 then split

Comment: You second group ends at a value of 2 for flag_1?

Comment: @ScottBoston Yes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grp = (df['flag_1']<500).cumsum()

pd.concat({n: g[1:] for n, g in tuple(df.groupby(grp)) if len(g) > 1}, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   flag_1  dd
0     500   7
1     598   8
2     595   8
3     500   7
4     540   7
5    5430   8
```

Comment: @ when flag is 500 and continous decreasing , this  is split condition

Comment: @waqarali what is continuous decreasing? flag_1? in your output example it doesn't show decreasing.

Comment: i edit my input , please check , value is decreasing 500, 498.... , so when value is 500 and until it decrease it will pe one segment of dataframe

Comment: @ Scott Boston  your solution did'nt work

Comment: @waqarali Your split condition isn't well enough defined?  How do I know when to stop counting after 500?   Stop at 1 or 2?  What about 3, 4, 10, 20, 100?

Comment: @ScottBoston  we need to stop when value start to increasing , for example 500,498,497, 498 , so here at 497 should stop the first group and wait for next time when happen 500 value then start to save data in other list and so on